# How to create nested ngFor loops for dynamically changing object child length in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I want to show a file tree in my Angular app. Of course a file tree can have multiple children in multiple levels.

Here is my example JSON object:

```
"root": {
    "element": {
        "displayName": "testFolder",
        "path": "testFolder/",
        "parent": ""
    },
    "children": [{
        "element": {
            "displayName": "folder1",
            "path": "testFolder/folder1/",
            "parent": "testFolder/"
        },
        "children": []
    }, {
        "element": {
            "displayName": "sub_folder",
            "path": "testFolder/sub_folder/",
            "parent": "testFolder/"
        },
        "children": [{
            "element": {
                "displayName": "testDir3",
                "path": "testFolder/sub_folder/testDir3/",
                "parent": "testFolder/sub_folder/"
            },
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

The `children` property can be arbitrarily nested. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as nested for ngfor is concerned, you can use something like this:

```
<template ngFor let-outer [ngForOf]="OuterArray" let-uterIndex="index">
         <template ngFor let-inner [ngForOf]="InnerArray" let-innerIndex="index">
         </template>
    </template>
```

and for traversing the entire file tree use it recursively.